# Memory issue in Party package, cforest

Tags: party

I am currently building random forest.

I have made my dataset very small, just only binary variable and three numeric variables (double precision). There are around 400,000 samples.

Model_cforest <- cforest(result ~ score1 + score2 + score3
                   , data=trainData, controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree=100))

I really don't think it would consume too much memory, as the package randomForest can handle this easily if I disable approximation.

However, in party package, cforest function, it ate up all of my memory (16GB, at least 12GB free) and still want more. I have to do nothing but terminate the program. I believe there must be something wrong in my setting, but I can not figure it out.

Would you please help me out? Thanks